# Dart compile error - Weird snippet of code in the code base

Tags: c++, c++11, fedora, dart

I came across this snippet of code while trying to compile Dart bleeding edge:

```
const uint8_t chars[kCharsLen] = { 1, 2, 127, 128, 192, 0, 255, -1 };
const String& str8 = String::Handle(String::New(chars, kCharsLen));
EXPECT_EQ(kCharsLen, str8.Length());
EXPECT_EQ(1, str8.CharAt(0));
EXPECT_EQ(127, str8.CharAt(2));
EXPECT_EQ(128, str8.CharAt(3));
EXPECT_EQ(0, str8.CharAt(5));
EXPECT_EQ(255, str8.CharAt(6));
EXPECT_EQ(255, str8.CharAt(7));
```

It seems odd to me that -1 would try to be assigned to a uint8_t. But I am reluctant to remove it becuase it might be a test to make sure you're compiler supports this. In fact the reason I came accross it is because the compiler on my Fedora 17 virtual machine (gcc 4.7)

Compile error:

> narrowing conversion of `-1` from `int` to `const uint8_t` {aka `const unsigned char`} inside `{ }` is ill-formed in C++11 [`-Werror=narrowing`]

Comment: Unsigned numbers 'wrap over' when outside of their bounds and so `-1` is just another way of saying 255. Not sure why you're getting a compiler error.

Comment: Not sure why 255 is used once, but -1 once as well.

Comment: Please post the compiler error.

Comment: @Pubby: Note: what you get when you turn -1 into an unsigned 8-bit integer is implementation defined. Yes, on virtually every compiler you run into, it will be 255. But as far as the standard is concerned, it could be anything.

Comment: Added the compilation error. Turns out I removed the -1 and haven't ran into issues yet, I am happily hacking away on the Dart compiler.

Comment: @NicolBolas no, not true. you get 255. Pubby is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a compiler error, that's a compiler *warning*. You probably are using `-Werror` which makes all warnings into errors.

You also might notice that `EXPECT_EQ(255, str8.CharAt(7));` is testing that  -1 will be 255.

Comment: Okay, I admit that my question is a little vague (very vague, actually). At this point, I understand clearly enough the nature of the error, and have fixed it by removing the odd test. However it strikes me as very odd, if the Dart build uses -Werror, that there would be such a test in the code base. Why am I the first to have come across this? Is it because I am the first to have tried using gcc 4.7, I doubt it. The question is one for a Dart dev, I first pinged the dart-dev IRC and since I got no response and it was written that the forum was not an official support channel, but Stack... was

Comment: I can confirm that Dart developers use somewhat older GCC versions, so don't hesitate to file bugs about these warnings. Some time ago, I got bit by this too -- and since I'm lazy, I simply commented out the `-Werror` line in `tools/gyp/configurations_make.gypi`.